# The argument prompt can not be converted to type String

Tags: sql, vb.net, executenonquery

My Code:

```
con.Open()
cmd = New SqlCommand("select max(LID) from Lieferanten", con)
Dim newIDSupplier As Double = cmd.ExecuteScalar
newIDSupplier += 1
con.Close()

con.Open()
cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT into LIEFERANTEN(LID, LNAME1) VALUES(@newIDSupplier, @companyName)", con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newIDSupplier", newIDSupplier)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

At `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` always comes the error message:

> The argument prompt can not be converted to type String

[image: Error]

Any help is apprecated.

Comment: You seem to forget to add another parameter: `@companyName`

Comment: I made earlier in my codecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyName", comanyName)

Comment: @Laura always use try catch. What data type is newIdSupplier

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried as below, also you should be passing company name:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newIDSupplier", newIDSupplier.ToString())
```